# Nondestructive alternative to splice?

Tags: javascript

Is there a nondestructive alternative to splice?

I'd like to keep a bank of data for a series are stripcharts. While I may have ~10,000 data points, perhaps I would only like to show 100 at a time as the user scrolls with a scrollbar. So if I have

```
var data = [];
// ... fill data with ~1000 data points
// ... data periodically updated and appended
stripchart.draw( data.splice(-100,100) ); // get last 100 data points
```

But I've destroyed my data, as splice is destructive. So... What's the slickest solution to grabbing a window of the data?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `slice` instead. It's like `substr` for arrays ;)

Comment: Well... that was easy. How embarrassing.